# Minecraft server automaticly moves to home folder

Tags: server, home-directory, minecraft

Me and my friends are having a Minecraft server on our Dropbox folder and whenever i start the sever it starts a new server and moves it into my home folder. If i already have a server in my home folder, it starts that one.

[image: Home Folder]

How can i run the server in directly from the dropbox folder? like Windows users can

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

SOLVED!:

Followed these instructions [[SOLVED] HOW DO I CHANGE LINUX MINECRAFT SERVER DIRECTORY?](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/139585-solved-how-do-i-change-linux-minecraft-server-directory/page__view__findpost__p__2154362)

How can i put this as solved when the one with the answer putted it as a comment?

Comment: You need read [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/162282-how-do-i-change-the-location-of-server-data-files/) or [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/139585-solved-how-do-i-change-linux-minecraft-server-directory/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an old question i'm just gonna write myself what i did :P

You need to cd to the folder within the terminal so if the minecraft_server.jar is in the folder `/home/username/Dropbox/minecraft_server/` you'll first need to cd to the folder and then open it, like this

```
cd /home/username/Dropbox/minecraft_server
java -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

Then it will load all the files that are in that folder and if there aren't any it will create them in there.

---

**UPDATE:**

Instead of writing this every time you want to turn on the server, you can do this:

**Step 1:**

make a folder in /opt called minecraft_server
and a file called run.sh

```
sudo mkdir /opt/minecraft_server
touch /opt/minecraft_server/run.sh
```

**Step 2: (Optional)**

Download a image that you want to be shown in the launcher and dash.

```
cd /opt/minecraft_server/
wget http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50254717/mineserver.png
```

**Step 3:**

edit the run.sh

```
sudo gedit /opt/minecraft_server/run.sh
```

and put this code in:

```
#!/bin/bash

## destination of the minecraft server file
cd /home/USERNAME/Dropbox/test/; 

## name of the minecraft server file
java -jar minecraft_server.jar;
```

**Step 4:**

create the .desktop file

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/minecraft_server.desktop
```

and put this code in:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Categories=Game
Exec=sh /opt/minecraft_server/run.sh
Name=Minecraft Server
Icon=/opt/minecraft/mineserver.png
#Icon taken from http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1328888-free-minecraft-server-icon/
```

Now you should be able to open the server within the server itself :)

Comment: Do I have to do this every time I open the server?

Comment: Thats what i do, but you could write a simple .desktop file if you wanna. I'll update the answer to make the .desktop file

Comment: there was no simple way of executing 2 commands from a .desktop file, so i had to create a run.sh file instead

Answer (score 0):

Check the ownership of the files in the dropbox folder with those that have been created in your home folder, compare the 2 different sets of ownership & permissions and make sure they are the same on both that you try and run.

You can find full permissions by using the ll command, i.e.:

```
    ll /root/to/folder
```

And if you find the ownership needs changing use:

```
    chown -R username:username /path/to//folder
```

If the permissions are incorrect:

```
    chmod -r <flags e.g. 775> /path/to/folder
```